# Is it possible to create an automation that exports a list (not a DE) to an FTP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, automation, data-extract

I need a way to automatically export a list (not DE) to an FTP. I know this is possible when using DE's, data extracts, and file transfer activities. However, no documentation seems to exists when trying to perform the same function on lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after I posted, thought others may want to know.

I created a query that looked at the _ListSubscribers data view. Example below:

```
Select [EmailAddress]
FROM 
_ListSubscribers
WHERE
ListID = XXXXXXXX
```

Then, I created an automation that runs this query, performs a data extract of the target DE, then a file transfer activity to move the target DE to an FTP.

This worked for my needs and may for others.